# Add custom attribute in order email

Tags: custom-attributes, order-email

I have made in my order email a notifacition when the product is out of stock and is backordered.

Now I have created two custom attributes for location of an spare part etc.
They are named invemtory_location_01 and inventory_location_02

I would like to add this text attribute to my order email so its much faster to find the specific part(s)

Could anyone help me how to do that:

my code is the following for default.phtml.

```
?>
<?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>
<?php $_order = $this->getItem()->getOrder() ?>
<tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
        <strong style="font-size:11px;"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong><?php if ($_item->getQtyBackordered()): ?><br><span style="font-size: 10px">(<?php echo $_item->getQtyBackordered()*1 ?> stk. bestilles hjem)</span><?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($this->getItemOptions()): ?>
        <dl style="margin:0; padding:0;">
            <?php foreach ($this->getItemOptions() as $option): ?>
            <dt><strong><em><?php echo $option['label'] ?></em></strong></dt>
            <dd style="margin:0; padding:0 0 0 9px;">
                <?php echo nl2br($option['value']) ?>
            </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $addInfoBlock = $this->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
        <?php if ($addInfoBlock) :?>
            <?php echo $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getSku($_item)) ?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;"><?php echo $_item->getQtyOrdered()*1 ?></td>
    <td align="right" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displaySalesPriceExclTax($_order->getStore()) || $this->helper('tax')->displaySalesBothPrices($_order->getStore())): ?>
            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displaySalesBothPrices($_order->getStore())): ?>
                <span class="label"><?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax'); ?>:</span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()); ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>
                <br />
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <small>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><small><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'],true,true); ?></small></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <small>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

I would like it to be show around under the product sku.

I use magento 1.9.2